# java.io.IOException: grpc failed in xamarin form

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, google-geocoder

I am using GoogleMaps nuget package for googlemap. I am converting position to address using googlemap geocoder.

```
var possibleAddresses = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(position);
```

I am checking internet connection before executing this statement. It is completely working fine if I dont turn my wifi on and then off. Even if I turn my wifi on and off it works but not always. I am getting error given below occasionally and when I get this error my app crashes and i have to open it again.

```
java.io.IOException: grpc failed
```

Comment: This in my knowledge happens when an async you try to reverse geocode for an address in the background thread and then that request i called multiple times before the first one is totally executed why not try applying a lock!

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have noticed exactly when it happen. When i turn my wifi off and turn my wifi on. Immediately after my app says wifi connected I execute this, then i get the error but as i said not always, it is occasionally but the situation is like that. May be even it says connected there is no full connection. I tried to check IsReachable function to make sure that I can ping a site but its also not working. 
So, I think if this is the case even blocking will not help i guess. after connection if i leave for a few second, it works perfectly. so weird. :(

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!

Comment: I havent found any solution yet, just assuming that user will not click on map as soon as wifi is connected . Surely, I will do as you asked once I got the solution.